# Subtracting data in a row based on similar values in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have sample of a much larger dataframe here:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': [27, 27, 30, 30, 43, 43, 50, 62, 62],
        'Time': [10, 30, 23.4, 28.6, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to be able to create a new column or a new dataframe that is able to subtract the Time values for each of the same numbers in the Name column.

Expected Outcome:

```
Name      Time Bucket
27            20
30            5.2
43            5
50            20
62            25
```

I am not too sure how I need to go about this.

Comment: how is 50 => 15 ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the logic please? Perhaps with an example?

Comment: There is no other 50 so it would just stay as is.

Comment: Ideally a loop or a couple lines of code would be able to look through the Name column and any time there are identical numbers it would subtract the values in the Time column.  These new values then can be put into a new dataframe.

Comment: so 50 should map to 20?

Comment: Yep that is a mistake on my part.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
out = df.assign(Time=df.groupby('Name')['Time'].diff().fillna(df['Time'])) \
        .drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last')
print(out)

# Output
   Name  Time
1    27  20.0
3    30   5.2
5    43   5.0
6    50  20.0
8    62  25.0
```

Comment: I had a similar logic, but did it in the `groupby` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupby`+`apply` to get the last item of the `diff` per group, and `fillna` for the case of a single element:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Time'].apply(lambda s: s.diff().fillna(s).iloc[-1])
```

Output:

```
Name
27    20.0
30     5.2
43     5.0
50    20.0
62    25.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

try using zip and reduce

```
data = {'Name': [27, 27, 30, 30, 43, 43, 50, 62, 62],
        'Time': [10, 30, 23.4, 28.6, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50]}

keys=set(data['Name'])
lst=list(zip(data['Name'],data['Time']))
print(lst)

results={}
for key in keys:
    value=functools.reduce(lambda x,y: y-x ,[x[1] for x in lst if x[0]==key])
    results[key]=value
    
print(results)
```

output:

```
 {43: 5, 50: 20, 30: 5.200000000000003, 27: 20, 62: 25}
```